# In SQLAlchemy, how can the name of a synonym be retained as an Alias (SQL AS) in generated SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to add a synonym field to a declarative class with a name that persists through to generated SQL, using SQL aliases (i.e. `AS`). This is so that other tools can consume the generated SQL with column names pre-set as desired.

Example:

```
class MyTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    column_a = Column(Integer)
    column_b = Column(Integer)

    my_syn = synonym("column_a")

    @hybrid_property
    def genuine_hybrid(self):
        return self.column_a + self.column_b

    @hybrid_property
    def fake_syn_hybrid(self):
        return self.column_a
```

The following SQL is generated for the final three attributes:

```
> print session.query(MyTable.my_syn)
SELECT my_table.column_a AS my_table_column_a
FROM my_table
> print session.query(MyTable.genuine_hybrid)
SELECT my_table.column_a + my_table.column_b AS genuine_hybrid
FROM my_table
> print session.query(MyTable.fake_syn_hybrid)
SELECT my_table.column_a AS my_table_column_a
FROM my_table
```

Only `genuine_hybrid` has its name used as a SQL Alias - the other two cases have the original column used.

Is there a way to force either the synonym or the second hybrid property to pass retain their names through to the generated SQL?

Comment: [`synonym`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#synonyms) is usually meant to be just an additional name for some (python model class) attribute. It won't introduce extra column selections or names in SQL.

Comment: @IljaEverilä That's fine, but the hybrid property does, and that's the behaviour I want.

Comment: Just return properly labeled version from your `fake_syn_hybrid`, pretty much what the answer has, except return the label object from the hybrid. Or do exactly as the answer, and label things when you have to.  Speculating, but your "genuine" hybrid does its labeling since it has to give some name where none existed (your returned expression has no "name").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `label` attribute on the column:

```
session.query(MyTable.column_a.label('my_syn'))
```

Comment: On the hybrid property too?